# SQL logic error exception while excel columns contain the Square brackets

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I have been trying to create a table with the column name [Year] in the SQLite. But, it throws an exception as SQL logic error or missing database
unrecognized token: "]".

Comment: Show us your example. It would be better for us to understand what you are doing wrongly

Comment: Square backets are special characters, and can't be used in column names.

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite (as with many other RDBMses), you can quote non-standard column names with double quotes ([Working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/0c48e/4/1)):

```
CREATE TABLE test( "[Year]" int)
```

You'll need to quote it everywhere you use it:

```
INSERT INTO test("[Year]") VALUES (2015);
SELECT "[Year]" FROM test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating table structure in SQL will not allow you to create column names with `square brackets []` , and why do you want to put square brackets in the first place?